# Fetching data after performing update using Bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js

I am using `save()` method (Bookshelf.js) to update data in PostgreSQL. I want to fetch the complete model(all columns) after updating how can I do that? It seems to me that `save()` method is returning only `id` and updated column. I might be doing it wrong so any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Sequelizejs we use this approach just call your whatever model in then function when operation performs successfully.same thin u can try here

```
new Author({id: 1, first_name: 'User'})
  .save({bio: 'Short user bio'}, {patch: true})
  .then(function(model) {
    //two approach 
//try this but not sure work in Bookshelf or not
    return model.fetchAll();
//or u can try 
           new Article().fetchAll()
            .then(function(articles) {
                 res.send(articles.toJSON());
            }).catch(function(error) {
          res.send('An error occured');
    });

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The .save() bookshelf method returns the updated object in the `attributes` field.

```
new User().save({ firstname: 'Foo', lastname: 'Bar' })
.then(data => {
  console.log(data.attributes);

  // You can also do this to remove Bookshelf Model methods
  data = data.toJSON();
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting it correct. You want to fetch all the columns of the row that is just updated. Then you can do this:

```
User.where({ name: name }).fetch().asCallback(function(err, existingEntry){
  if(existingEntry){
      existingEntry.save({ 
          address: address,
      }).asCallback(function(err, updatedColumns){
          console.log(existingEntry); // Here you will get all the columns of the updated row
          console.log(updatedColumns); // Here you can get the columns that you have just updated
      })
  }
})
```

Worked for me if that's the case I have mentioned will work for all. One more thing this code is for bookshelf version 0.8.2. Don't get it wrong